# Problems trying to access/attach ESE database using ManagedEsent

Tags: c#, .net, database, esent, extensible-storage-engine

I'm trying to read an ESE database (.edb) using the ManagedEsent libraries. However, I'm getting an error at the time of setting up the database. The error appears to be coming up at the time of attaching the database (calling JetAttachDatabase()).

The error message I'm getting is "Soft recovery is intended on a backup database. Restore should be used instead".

Below is my code:

```
JET_INSTANCE instance;
JET_SESID sesid;

Microsoft.Isam.Esent.Interop.SystemParameters.DatabasePageSize = 8 * 1024;

Api.JetCreateInstance(out instance, Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
Api.JetInit(ref instance);

JET_DBID dbid;
JET_COLUMNID columnid;
JET_TABLEID tableid;
JET_COLUMNDEF columndef = new JET_COLUMNDEF();

Api.JetBeginSession(instance, out sesid, null, null);

Api.JetAttachDatabase(sesid, @"Blah.edb", AttachDatabaseGrbit.None);

Api.OpenDatabase(sesid, @"Blah.edb", out dbid, OpenDatabaseGrbit.None);
```

The exception I'm getting is:

```
Microsoft.Isam.Esent.Interop.EsentSoftRecoveryOnBackupDatabase
Soft recovery is intended on a backup database. Restore should be used instead
at Microsoft.Isam.Esent.Interop.Api.Check(Int32 err) in e:\src\codeplex_svn\codeplex\EsentInterop\Api.cs:line 2894
at Microsoft.Isam.Esent.Interop.Api.JetAttachDatabase(JET_SESID sesid, String database, AttachDatabaseGrbit grbit) in e:\src\codeplex_svn\codeplex\EsentInterop\Api.cs:line 372
```

Any ideas what could be causing this? Is the .edb file I'm attaching possible invalid?

Answer (score 2):

I was able to access the database after running the EsentUtl utility to repair the database file:

```
esentutl /p Blah.edb
```

After running this, I can attach/open the database and read from the tables in the database.
I'm not sure what the repair has actually done to the file though (e.g. if it is possibly now missing some data or something).

Comment: Yes, 'rePair' should really be called 'Salvage'. It does all it can do to make a database readable. if it can't figure out how to salvage a table, it will just delete the table. It's designed to allow you get access to *some* of your data, and there is no guarantee at all that you won't lose a big chunk of data.

As for what it did, you can look at the 'blah.integ.raw' file that rePair creates. It lists all of the actions it performed.

Comment: Thanks Martin for directing me to the .raw file. I had a look at it and there are a few lines there which are a bit concerning:                                           
                         ERROR: database was not shutdown cleanly (Dirty Shutdown)

WARNING: Database file is too big (expected 299536 pages, file is 299537 pages)
changing signature of Blah.edb

scanning the database from page 1 to page 299537
error -1018 reading page 299537. the page has been zeroed out so online backup will work
Inserting page 299537 into BadPages table

Comment: I'm not sure how the the application does its db "backup" - it must be doing it without shutting down the server first, based on the error messages. I noticed too that there was a .log file (edb00A55.log) and a .pat file (Blah.pat) in the same folder as the Blah.edb I took. Should I somehow be making use of these files to recover the database without losing any data?

Comment: Yes, the Backup process is done online, and it's intentional that the database will be 'dirty' during this state, requiring the information from the log files as well. It's necessary to do a Hard Recovery (restore), and that also includes the Patch File.

Answer (score 1):

Where did you get the database?
What you did should work for a Cleanly-shut-down database. You don't need the transaction log files for these databases.
But there are also Dirty databases (when JetTerm didn't complete gracefully). You'll need the transaction log files for those.
And also Backed-up databases, which are slightly different again. For these databases, you need to call JetRestore.

-martin

Comment: Thanks Martin for your response. The database is from a third-party application (e.g. not Microsoft / Windows database). Are Backed-up database files different to the live (.edb) data files? (I previously tried running the JetRestore on my .edb file but it didn't work, probably because it's not an actual backup file?)

Comment: Yes, they are indeed a bit different. The reason stems from the days of Tape Backups, when you had to write a file sequentially. The database header changes while writing out the large database file, and by the end of copying so much data, you need to write an updated header. This gets stuck at the end of the file. JetRestore needs to know how to deal with this difference.